# Why do I get this error in Eclipse - can it be that Java runtime version is incompatible?

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors

In Eclipse(version 3.6.2.M201102101200/Helios service release 2). I am getting a strange error when I run a large Java project called ACE toolkit. Below is a picture:

[image]

What are possible reasons it would do this?

can it be that Java runtime version is incompatible? The project was built for Java 1.5, but I have 1.6 running.

I appreciate any tips or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be any number of reasons for eclipse crashing, from insufficient memory to a misbehaving plugin. The first place to start troubleshooting would be the `C:\path\to\your\workspace\.metadata\.log` file. You might find something helpful if you examine the end of this file soon after eclipse crashes.

### From the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html):

> Eclipse has a log file where problems are recorded and usually this is the first thing that an Eclipse developer asks for when you report a problem. The log file can be found in a couple of places:
>
> **Workspace log** - This is the most common location for the log file, It is stored in your workspace in the meta-data directory. Check out
> workspace/.metadata/.log.
>
> **Configuration log** - Sometimes information is recored in the configuration log file instead of the workspace log. (especially if
> the workspace hasn't been created yet, there isn't one, or it cannot
> be created) Check your configuration area for a configuration log
> file. (configuration/.log)
>
> **Startup** - Occasionally problems happen in the system really early before there is a workspace and before there is a configuration area.
> This means that there is nowhere to write the log file so information
> is written to the console, See the notes below on running with a
> console to get these messages.